# How to queue files in FDM like in IDM

Tags: download-manager

I want to add 4 files next to each other in FDM list.
I want to know how I can do this in FDM to make it download files after each other without my attention? I mean if download #1 finished , it should start #2 download automatically.
If you've worked with IDM you know what I'm saying (ie in IDM it is Queue). How can I achieve that in FDM?

Answer (score 9):

I am the asker. I finaly found what Ive wanted.
I followed the instruction from here:
http://en.kioskea.net/faq/26927-free-download-manager-set-the-maximum-number-of-simultaneous-downloads-allowed

#### The summary:

You can configure Free Download Manager to limit the number of simultaneous downloads.
Simply follow the below manipulation:

- Launch the program and click on the Options tab > Settings:
- Go to Downloads > Downloads
- Select the Traffic usage mode of your choice, then in the "Maximum number of running downloads" section, select "Set to".
- Enter a value in "corresponding the the number of downloads"
- Repeat the operation for the other traffic usage modes.
- Click on OK to validate.

I hope I helped anyone with the same issue.